# Gtk3 address bar widget

Tags: gtk3

Is there a known implementation for an address bar in Gtk3? I'm looking for something like in iPhone and Android e-mail clients, where the already given addresses are converted into buttons.

Edit:
I'm currently developing for gtk-3.4. The GtkLinkButton suggested by mike below seems promising, but is there a way to add it to a GtkEditable so it could be deleted with e.g the backspace button, or for text to be inserted before/after it?

Comment: Are you talking about internet address, or local filesystem address ?
I suggest you to look into nautius code.

Comment: Not really. Think about something like the tag input bar on stack overflow when you ask a question. In theory, the addresses I refer to in my question should be anything...

Answer (score 0):

When posting about gtk3 in particular you should list what version your using because there's depreciated code as you change versions. The newest stable version is 3.4.
I think what your looking for is GtkLinkButton. 
[Official gtk+-3.4 manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkLinkButton.html)